# How to style custom pagelayout field validation errors?

Tags: page-layout

I created a custom pagelayout with some fields. One of these fields is required. When it is empty and you save the page you will get an validation error. It is now black. How can I change it to the red color?

[Here](http://s13.postimg.org/k6oanx60m/Naamloos.jpg) is an example of the validation message just in black color.

Comment: The only thing I did is creating a new pagelayout and drag and drop the fields from sharepoint designer.

Comment: In your custom pagelayout, choose the span using CSS and set `color` to red.

Answer (score 0):

the css-class `ms-error` does paint a span red if that is what you want.

Comment: the span is created when the field is empty and you do a postback. So the span with the warning is not available in the pagelayout.

Comment: @Ola you should use jQuery for this then.